# Problem while running "newgrp" command in script

Tags: scripting, aix, group

I want to change the working group in my script. So I wrote a line `newgrp test_grp1` in my script. But my script is automatically exited after running this line. Are there any solution to overcome this problem?

```
#/bin/ksh
...
newgrp test_grp1
...
```

**Note:** I am using Unix AIX OS.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`newgrp` starts a subshell with the group you specified. So that line in your script will not finish until that subshell is done.

The handling of `newgrp` is also different if you're using `bash` or `ksh`. `ksh` implements it as a built-in command that is equivalent to `exec /usr/bin/newgrp [group]`. So, like `exec`, `newgrp` never returns. (See some documentation [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.baseadmn/doc/baseadmndita/korn_shell_spec_builtin_cmd_desc.htm).)

If you want it to return, and want to execute commands in that subshell with changed group identity, you can use redirection.

For example:

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo "Before newgrp"
/usr/bin/newgrp users <<EONG
echo "hello from within newgrp"
id
EONG
echo "After newgrp"
```

Notice: `/usr/bin/newgrp` is called explicitly to avoid the implicit `exec` from `ksh`. The last command in that script will run within the original shell, with the original group identity.

Comment: love from me, saved the day using `newgrp docker`

Comment: just a note that, the closing EONG should not be indented

Answer (score 3):

Once a process has been started, it cannot gain any extra privileges. So you can't gain a group membership in the middle of a script. You can run the whole script with the extra group membership:

```
newgrp test_grp1
/path/to/script
```

You can't change your real GID mid-script. If you really need that, switch to a language where you can, such as Perl. It's rare to need to change your real GID though, since it doesn't matter much. Usually it's enough to make the occasional call to `chgrp` (create files with no group permissions first, then run `chgrp`, then add group permissions; if you create files with group permissions, there's a race condition: a user who is in the first group could open the file before you have time to run `chgrp`).

Comment: Is there any reason this couldn't be done by wrapping the second half of the script in a subshell?

Comment: @Caleb Not a subshell strictly speaking, but you can pass a script to the shell invoked by `newgrp` on its standard input, as in [Mat's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18897/problem-while-running-newgrp-command-in-script/18902#18902).