# Set to non-default user group upon login in bash

Tags: shell-script, permissions, bashrc

Upon login with .bashrc, how to set the user's group to a non-default one, say targetgroup?

Specifically, my problem is that I can execute, on the command line:

```
newgrp - targetgroup
```

but when I include this line in .bashrc, the terminal freezes upon login.

This question relates to [Problem while running "newgrp" command in script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18897/problem-while-running-newgrp-command-in-script) but I have insufficient reputation to comment.
So I tried:

```
echo "Before newgrp"
/usr/bin/newgrp - targetgroup <<EONG
echo "hello from within newgrp"
id
EONG
echo "After newgrp"
```

which gives:

```
Before newgrp
Before newgrp
Before newgrp
Before newgrp
Before newgrp
Before newgrp
Before newgrp
Before newgrp
^C
After newgrp
```

so the trick for KornShell does not appear to work for bash, as I had to exit with ^C.

Is there any way to make `newgrp` work or another .bashrc line that would set the group to targetgroup upon every login? (NB I don't have superuser priviledges.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For CentOS 6 you can try adding (without dash)

```
newgrp targetgroup
```

to your `.bash_profile`.

At least for CentOS 6.10 this changes the effective group to `targetgroup` in the interactive shell

- for new login shells
- after `source ~/.bash_profile`

Group will not be changed when "only" starting another `bash` or `source ~/.bashrc` in an existing console.

Comment: It does something different, but still does not work:

Before newgrp
hello from within newgrp
uid=535(myuser) gid=528(targetgroup) groupes=535(myuser),528(targetgroup) contexte=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
After newgrp
[myuser@machine ~]$ vim test7
[myuser@machine ~]$ ls -lrt
total 52944
[...]
-rw-rw-r--. 1 myuser mygroup        0 22 mar 17:21 test7

Comment: Hi Gene, I do not fully get what you want to achive with the second part "After newgrp". When I "uid=1000(user) gid=100(users)" add "newgrp cdrom" to my .bashrc and execute "bash", then use "id" within this bash it shows "uid=1000(user) gid=24(cdrom) groups=24(cdrom),20(dialout),... So the effective group has changed and e.g. "touch xyz; ls -al xyz" results in
"-rw-r--r-- 1 user cdrom 0 Mar 22 22:33 xyz"

Comment: I was indeed going for something like your "touch xyz; ls -al xyz". However, with your test, I still get the same default mygroup: "-rw-rw-r--. 1 myuser mygroup 0 22 mar 17:51 xyz". Maybe the machine I have access to is missing some updates... it just seems that newgrp should be a basic command :\

Comment: Hi Gene, most likely we are missing something obvious :) What linux distribution and version are you using? And how to you reload your .bashrc, after you have added the "newgrp" line? (Typing "bash" on the commandline and continue from there? Using "source .bashrc" ... ?)

Comment: Hi Marvin... With the command "lsb_release -a" it returns:
"LSB Version: :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description: CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
Release: 6.5
Codename: Final" ... Yeah, I've been using "source .bashrc" to test it... and starting other ssh sessions sometimes to double-check as well. It'd be awesome if you could think of something that'd fix this! ^__^

Comment: Hi Gene, sorry, but my original answer was not working for CentOS 6, hopefully my edited answer can be of some help now :)

Comment: Good catch!! Note to self: the linux distribution is on the suspects list. ^__^